# How do I make my bottom sheet modal scrollable?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheetDialogeFragment with this layout. I want to scroll whole fragment view instead of gridview only. I tried nesting LinearLayout with scrollview and NestedScrollView, but in both cases modal don't even slide up to the top.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/heart"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` and Use `RecyclerView` insteadof `GridView`.. You should not be using `GridView` in 2019 ...

Comment: I'm actually a developer from 2016, trying to work again in 2019. Thanks for info @ADM